# Order by count of association through join table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a show with many episodes, and episodes have many people through contributions.  **(see diagram below)**

I added `has_many :people, through: :contributions` to `Show` so I can do:  `game_of_thrones.people.count`, and even:

```
  has_many :actors, -> { joins(:roles).merge(Role.actors).distinct },
    through: :contributions, source: :person
```

-

```
game_of_thrones.actors.count
```

But what I would like to do is create a list of actors on game_of_thrones or breaking_bad, etc, ordered by the number of appearances on the show.

example:

1. Jon Snow: 9 episodes
2. Arya Stark: 8 episodes
3. Joffrey Lannister: 5 episodes
4. Tyrion Lannister: 2 episodes

[image: Database schema of a Show with many Episodes. Episodes has many people through contributions.]

My question is a two parter.

1. How do I return a list of top actors on a show ordered by their contribution count?
2. Should I be doing this through ActiveRecord or SQL queries.  What would be a good reference to understand this better so I can stop bothering stack overflow?

   ```
   class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :episodes, inverse_of: :show
     has_many :contributions, through: :episodes
     has_many :people, through: :contributions

     has_many :actors, -> { joins(:roles).merge(Role.actors) },
       through: :contributions, source: :person
   end

   class Episode < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :show, inverse_of: :episodes
     has_many :contributions, inverse_of: :episode
     has_many :roles, through: :contributions
     has_many :people, through: :contributions
   end

   class Contribution < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :episode, inverse_of: :contributions
     belongs_to :person, inverse_of: :contributions
     belongs_to :role, inverse_of: :contributions
   end

   class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :contributions, inverse_of: :person
     has_many :episodes, through: :contributions
     has_many :roles, through: :contributions

     scope :actors, -> { joins(:roles).merge(Role.actors) }
   end

   class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :contributions, inverse_of: :role
     has_many :people, through: :contributions
     has_many :episodes, through: :contributions

     scope :actors, -> { where(name: 'Actor') }
   end
   ```

failed queries: `game_of_thrones.people.joins(:contributions).distinct.joins(:episodes).where("episodes.show_id = 1").order("count(episodes.show_id) desc")`

```
game_of_thrones.guests.joins(:contributions).order("count(contribuions.id) desc")
```

Comment: Formatted question well, doesn't mean others will do ur Home work! plz share show, [what you have tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I've tried all sorts of queries but I don't understand ActiveRecord enough to know it's limitations (ie, is it robust enough to do what I'm asking) and I don't know SQL enough to get the query working.  Hence part two of the question, what resources are there for sql queries like this.

Comment: you can mention whatever you have tried with specifc problem in those queries

Comment: game_of_thrones.people.joins(:contributions).distinct.joins(:episodes).where("episodes.show_id = 1").order("count(episodes.show_id) desc")

game_of_thrones.guests.joins(:contributions).order("count(contribuions.id) desc")

Added more info to question.

Comment: Is this an uncommon thing to do?  Can anyone point me to a similar stack question?  My ignorance in terminology is hindering my search.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it:

```
  def top_contributors
    self.people.select("people.id, count(contributions.id) AS contribution_count").
      joins(:contributions).
      joins(:episodes).
      group("people.id").
      order("contribution_count DESC").
      limit(5)
  end
```

Though I think this is counting all of a person's contributions regarless of shows.